# "User is online" green dot icon for Android material design

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Where can I find the green color small dot icon that shows "user is online" for material design Android? 
NOTE: I don't think that it is available in this https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline and this https://materialdesignicons.com/ site.

Comment: https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/checkbox-blank-circle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="10dp"
    android:height="10dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#05b714"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0"/>
</vector>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

> USE LIKE THIS

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:src="@drawable/kid"
        app:civ_border_color="#000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_online" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: A vector drawable for a simple circle? Why not just use a shape drawable..?